# Watson IoT Cloudant DBs are not being created automatically for historical data

Tags: cloudant, watson-iot

I am following the instructions in

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-parti/

however, no databases are created automatically in the Cloudant instance. The data from my sensor is flowing in fine, but I cannot store it. The Extensions page of the IOT dashboard indicates that Cloudant has been configured.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Apparently the DB creation is not immediate. When I checked back after a couple of days, the DBs were there. Someone should add this to the instructions.

Comment: Hi there, it's happening to me too: I've given the permission after selecting the timezone, timespan and db name.
Now WIoTP says that Historical Data Storage is not configured even though I received no errors.
If I try to configure it again it hangs without asking me for permission (a transparent poup with the circle thingy that rotates but nothing happens). I can't see any new DB on Cloudant, just like you

Comment: I've tried again after an hour or so, the cloudant DB got created in a matter of minute and the status passed to "Configured".
Strange :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary problem with cloudant database creation around the time you posted this question.  It should now be fixed, please let us know if you still are experiencing the problem.